# image and spanlabel render default output in List [CodenameOne]

Tags: list, codenameone, renderer

I took one blank container and add ImageViewer & Spanlabel. Same is render in list but it shows me default output (which i put for test). I Try both ways dynamic and manual still output is same. Even i try to work with Multi-List but it not taking renderer.

Here is My code :

```
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> a = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Image image=fetchResourceFile().getImage("puzzle_icon.png");
    m.put("gSR_image", image);
    m.put("gSR_label", "Puzzle");
    a.add(m);
    cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(a));
```

see this output

[image: see this output]

my renderer screen

[image: my renderer screen]

output must be my image and Puzzle written below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something problem in spanlabel so replace the spanlabel with textarea and unchecked editable which works similar as above .

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> a = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Image image=fetchResourceFile().getImage("puzzle_icon.png");
m.put("gSR_image", image);
**m.put("gSR_textarea", "its working");**
a.add(m);
cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(a));
```

Comment: Another alternative highlighted here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_generic_list_cell_renderer is to rename the `gSR_image` to `gSR_imageFixed` which will prevent the renderer from trying to fetch it from data.

Comment: Forgot to add that SpanLabel/Button don't work very well in a renderer. You should use a TextArea and style it accordingly. Also notice that the above components will **NOT** line break dynamically as they do in a regular container.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog your solution work with text but for image same is not working. I tried with add `Fixed` word at end but this work with label not `ImageViewer` and same is force `Label` to pick image which is set in renderer. Finally solution which work is to replace `ImageViewer` with `Label` and name must be without `Fixed` word at end. `Image image=fetchResourceFile().getImage("puzzle_icon.png");
        m.put("gSR_image", image);` this working perfect now.

Comment: Are you embedding an `ImageViewer` into a renderer??? That is not a good idea. Don't do that. If you need the scaling use `ScaleImageLabel`.